# Release IPs assigned by ifconfig

Tags: linux, networking, debian

Is there anyway to release IPs that were assigned using the following command

```
ifconfig ens3 inet6 add MYIPV6IP/64
```

If I restart the system all the IPs assigned with ifconfig will be released, how can I do that without doing a system reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ip` from iproute2 should be present on most recent systems:

```
ip -6 addr flush dev ens3 scope global
```

As a general rule, the Linux variants of `ifconfig` and `route` severely lack features. Even when they *do* seem to have the same features, don't get used to them.